# How to compile visual C++ program with additional libraries

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010, visual-c++-2008

I defined source & header -"MathCore.h" & "MathCore.cpp"
MathCore.h as below code :

```
#ifdef MATHCORE_EXPORTS
#define MATHCORE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHCORE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

MATHCORE_API bool isPowOf_Two(unsigned int n);
MATHCORE_API bool isFormOf_tpnmo(unsigned int n);
MATHCORE_API int isolate_LST( int x);


// This class is exported from the MathCore.dll
class MATHCORE_API MathEngine {
public:
    MathEngine(void);
    // TODO: add your methods here.
};

extern MATHCORE_API int nMathCore;

MATHCORE_API int fnMathCore(void);
```

and I generated lib - "MathCore.lib" and respective dll-"MathCore.dll" from visual studio 2008,then I created C++ source file-"t.cpp" in a different folder which uses functions defined in MathCore,for simplicity I put MathCore.lib and MathCore.dll within same folder.
t.cpp as following

```
#pragma comment(lib, "MathCore.lib")
#include <iostream>
#include "MathCore.h"

using namespace std;

MATHCORE_API bool isPowOf_Two(unsigned int n);
MATHCORE_API bool isFormOf_tpnmo(unsigned int n);

int main()
{

    while(1){
    unsigned int x;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<isPowOf_Two(x)<<"\n";
    cout<<x<<"\n";
    }
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

My problem is.. without using Visual Studio I want to compile the t.cpp using batch file say -"run.bat"
so I included "vcvarsall.bat" and "vcvars32.bat" to same source folder,my "run.bat" commands like this ....

```
@echo off
call "vcvarsall.bat"
call "vcvars32.bat"
echo off
cl /O2 t.cpp /link MathCore.lib
@if ERRORLEVEL == 0 (
goto good
)

@if ERRORLEVEL != 0 (
goto bad
)

:good
echo "clean compile"
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
goto end

:bad
echo "error or warning"
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
goto end

:end
```

when I run "run.bat" it creates "t.obj" without "t.exe" I think it does not link MathCore.lib,I want to know how to compile visual C++ source with additional libraries and includes in commandline I chekc visual studio commandline arguements It was not help me to solve this problem.

PLEASE ANYONE KNOW EXACT COMMANDLINE ARGUEMENTS TO COMPILE A VISUAL C++ SOURCE FILE WITH NEEDED LIBS and Header FILES 
please refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h.aspx

Comment: As you tagged with Visual Studio, [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293626.aspx) might be easier. You can configure your project properties to get it compiling in the IDE and then just automate the build afterwards.

Comment: I want to compile the sources without using Visual Studio,I want to execute a bat and do the stuff..Please help.. Problem with linking library I refered these things
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h.aspx

Comment: That's what MSBuild does - you don't run the IDE at all and you can build from a `.bat` file.

Comment: Please could you send me the helpful links how to achieve it using MSBuild,I am less experience on the building stuff,I  thinnk MSBuild uses Visual Studio property files(props,sln) and other stuff?

Comment: The link is in my first comment - but if you can build through Visual Studio you basically just run MSBuild and give it the .sln name.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++Builder? That tag does not belong.

Answer (score 0):

Without khowing actual error It will be difficult to say.

I created one sample lib and tried to link it. To make it work, I changed line below.

> cl /O2 t.cpp /link MathCore.lib

to

> cl /O2 t.cpp /MDd  MathCore.lib

Would be nice if you run *.bat (run.bat, in your case) and paste the error here.

[PS: I am not able to add comment hence adding reply]

Comment: thanks for the answering.Problem is when I remove 
"cout<<isPowOf_Two(x)<<"\n";"
line from  my t.cpp it compile perfectly and generate "t.exe",Problem is I cannot use function defined in MathCore.h,I think my "MathCore.lib" not linked well.

Comment: Did you tried removing lines below from your caller function?

MATHCORE_API bool isPowOf_Two(unsigned int n);
MATHCORE_API bool isFormOf_tpnmo(unsigned int n);